# WAR not deploying on Tomcat [NameNotFoundException]

Tags: tomcat8

I'm trying to deploy a WAR on Tomcat but I get exceptions in some of my environment variables as in this one

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [smartconnect.filestorelocation] is not bound in this Context.
```

I have the names inside `Environment` tags in the server.xml

```
  <Environment name="smartconnect.filestorelocation" value="/var/www/html/me/smart/filestore" type="java.lang.String" override="false" />
  <Environment name="smartconnect.dataqueue_cleanup_days" value="30" type="java.lang.Integer" override="false" /> 
  <Environment name="smartconnect.spatial_ref_sys_table" value="public.spatial_ref_sys" type="java.lang.String" override="false" />
  <Environment name="smartconnect.number_background_threads" value="5" type="java.lang.Integer" override="false" />
  <Environment name="smartconnect.work_item_history_days_available" value="5" type="java.lang.Integer" override="false" />
  <Environment name="smartconnect.changelog_cleanup_days" value="5" type="java.lang.Integer" override="false" />
  <Environment name="smartconnect.ca_export_days_available" value="5" type="java.lang.Integer" override="false" />
  <Environment name="smartconnect.sync_download_hours_available" value="5" type="java.lang.Integer" override="false" />
  <Environment name="smartconnect.cleanup_task_interval_hours" value="5" type="java.lang.Integer" override="false" />
```

The server's `context.xml` is like this:

```
<Context>

<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm"
        dataSourceName="jdbc/smart"
        userTable="connect.users" userNameCol="username" 
        userCredCol="password" userRoleTable="connect.user_roles" roleNameCol="role_id"
        localDataSource="true">
        <CredentialHandler className="org.wcs.smart.connect.apache.BcryptCredentialHandler"/>
    </Realm>
</Realm>

<ResourceLink global="org.wcs.smart.connect.datasource.postgresql" name="jdbc/smart"/>
<ResourceLink global="smartconnect.filestorelocation" name="smartconnect.filestorelocation"/>
<ResourceLink global="smartconnect.dataqueue_cleanup_days" name="smartconnect.dataqueue_cleanup_days"/>
<ResourceLink global="smartconnect.spatial_ref_sys_table" name="smartconnect.spatial_ref_sys_table"/>
<ResourceLink global="smartconnect.number_background_threads" name="smartconnect.number_background_threads"/>
<ResourceLink global="smartconnect.work_item_history_days_available" name="smartconnect.work_item_history_days_available"/>
<ResourceLink global="smartconnect.changelog_cleanup_days" name="smartconnect.changelog_cleanup_days"/>
<ResourceLink global="smartconnect.ca_export_days_available" name="smartconnect.ca_export_days_available"/>
<ResourceLink global="smartconnect.sync_download_hours_available" name="smartconnect.sync_download_hours_available"/>
<ResourceLink global="smartconnect.cleanup_task_interval_hours" name="smartconnect.cleanup_task_interval_hours"/>
<ResourceLink global="mail/Session" name="mail/Session"/>
</Context>
```

Does anybody know how can I fix this error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have [smartconnect.filestorelocation] variable inside context.xml and not in server.xml as well? I think you are referencing in context.xml on variable smartconnect.filestorelocation which is not defined in server.xml

Comment: Sorry, I didn't copy that line in my post but it is in the `server.xml` . I've edited it now.